# What's workDirectory attribute really for?

Tags: java, mule, mule-studio

According to the Mule documentation, the workDirectory attribute is used for the following:

> If you require moving input files before they are processed by Mule,
>   then assign a working directory (in the same file system) with this
>   parameter

However, I don't understand the need for moving a file before it's processed. Does it prevent some kind of multiple reads done by Mule? If that's the case, why isnt' the file always moved before being processed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will prevent a number of problems that could happen:

- if multiple systems read the same directory
- if you have a limited space in the unit storing the inbould file
- if the file is volatile and too large to be processed before it's removed
- ...you can name others on your use case

Comment: I don't get the point "too large to be processed before it's removed". First: How large is that large? And second: How does workDirectory help on that case? You'll have the same problem with the work directory.

Comment: If you have input, work and done. If the file is, let's say 10M, you can process 100k per second for whatever reason and the files are removed or overwrited every 10 seconds, you might want to copy from input to work and process from there. Otherwise, the file would dissapear and dipending on the operating system you might get some unexpected EOF or not.

Comment: So, as far as I understand, the key is the relation between how long it takes to process the file, and the pollingFrequency value. Is that correct?

Comment: yes, also the stability of the input files. If they are likely to be overwritten or deleted, then workdir can be useful.

Comment: Great, thanks! Only one issue about your answer to consider it completely correct: Limited space in the unit storage is not a reason for using workDirectory, as this directory has to be on the same unit that reads the input.

Comment: not necessarily, it's not uncommon to read from a netbios or NFS mounted remote filesystem.

Comment: That's correct, the documentation puts same file system, not same unit. Thanks again!